# Split txt file delimited by space or comma and concatenate a suffix in a .bat

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, split, concatenation

I need to split some text in lines and concatenate with a sufix using Windows cmd .bat.

I recieve lists that came like:

```
9448
9453
9463
9464
9474
9477
```

or like:

```
9448, 9453, 9463, 9464, 9474, 9477
```

So I need to put every number of these added with .jpg, like:

```
9448.jpg
9453.jpg
9463.jpg
```

them the program would run the way I need.

here goes the code I'm working on:

```
echo off

for %%a in (.) do set currentfolder=%%~na
set src_folder= %CD%
set dst_folder= "%currentfolder%_SELECTED/%date:/=%%"
md %dst_folder%
for /f %%i in (list.txt) DO copy %%i %dst_folder%\%%i
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run two nested `for` loops: one to split into lines and another to split a line into separate tokens. So you don't have to care, which of the two formats the file has.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (list.txt) do (
  for %%b in (%%a) do (
    ECHO copy "%%b.jpg" "%dst_folder%\%%b"
  )
)
```

Note: it isn't clear to me, what you exactly try to do. Adapt the `ECHO` line until the output is what you want, then remove the `ECHO`.

Comment: I'm trying to separete 40 or 50 .jpg files from a folder that have hundreds of images